# How to determine what part of the sentence a gerund phrase is modifying?

Tags: gerunds, adverbials

> Most of us fall between the two extremes of Psalm 22 and the
>   anti-psalm of the man facing Nazi oppression.
>
> Welch, Edward T.. Side by Side (p. 39). Crossway. Kindle Edition.

Take this sentence for example. Does "facing Nazi oppression" modify "the man" or "the anti-psalm" or "Most of us"? My intuition says it should be the nearest one, which in this case is "the man". But is there any occasion where the gerund phrase modifies a farther object?

By the way, feel free to correct me if there is any misusage of grammatical terms.

Comment: An "anti-psalm" is unlikely to face Nazi oppression... "the man [who is] facing Nazi oppression"

Comment: ... and it is not a gerund...

Answer (score 1):

> *Most of us fall between the two extremes of Psalm 22 and the*
>   *anti-psalm of* [*the man **facing Nazi oppression***].

The natural interpretation is that the gerund-participial clause in bold is a modifier in the bracketed noun phrase.

Gerund-participials (and past-participials) as modifiers in noun phrase structure are semantically similar to relative clauses: compare *the man who is facing Nazi oppression*.

It is possible to postpose a modifying clause, as in

*I lent a book to Ed* [*containing all the information he needed*],

where the bracketed subordinate clause is modifying "book".